# Importing OVA file Issue

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an ova file that I need to import as a VM instance in Google Cloud Computer Engine.

The OS of the ova file is not known and so it produces an error when importing.

I want to know if there is a workaround solution to this problem.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the gcloud command tool and specifying the operating system manually. Please see the documentation from Google below and an example command on this. You can either do this utilizing the cloud shell provided from the console, or by downloading the google cloud SDK and authenticating it with your account. Make sure you have adequate permissions to upload the OVA file to your storage bucket, and to create Compute engine resources. "Compute engine admin" and "Storage object admin" would be way more than you need.

gcloud compute instances import my-instance --os=ubuntu-1604 --source-uri=gs://my-bucket/Ubuntu.ova

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-ovf-files#import_ova_file